# Пройтись по ключам начиная с определенного. Словарь python

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Есть следующий код:

```py
dic = {'A':213, 'B':1424, 'F':412, 'Gs':asf}
for key in dic:
    print(key)
```

Как можно проитерировать его, начиная со второго ключа?
Или, например, с ключа `F`?

Comment: Никак. Для таких целей стоит использовать список или кортеж. Структуры, кстати, можно комбинировать. Например, попробуйте воспользоваться списком словарей.

Comment: @nomnoms12, почему никак?? Начиная с Python 3.7 порядок элементов заданный при создании / вставке - гарантируется стандартом языка. Для более ранних версий можно воспользоваться `OrderedDict`...

Comment: @MaxU Я немного некорректно сформулировал свой комментарий выше. Я имел в виду, что это нельзя сделать с помощью методов класса `dict`. Нельзя взять срез словаря и т. п. В своём ответе Вы делаете это с помощью взятия среза со списка, который сгенерировали через метод словаря `keys()`. Так, конечно, можно. Это ответ на вопрос автора и в целом хорошее решение. Но оно не тривиальное. Это логика, которая не касается словарей. Вот, что я имел в виду. Поэтому и посоветовал использовать автору список.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В CPython реализации Python 3.6 элементы словаря сохраняют порядок данный им при создании. Это деталь реализации, *не гарантированная* стандартом языка.

[Начиная с Python 3.7 - это гарантированное поведение для любой реализации Python](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html):

> - the insertion-order preservation nature of dict objects has been declared to be an official part of the Python language spec.

---

Соответственно, для Python 3.7+ вы можете сделать:

```
In [6]: list(dic.keys())[2:]
Out[6]: ['F', 'Gs']
```

Для более ранних версий вы можете воспользоваться `OrderedDict`, [как вам уже посоветовал @Хачатур Саркисян](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1004378/211923):

```
In [9]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [10]: odic = OrderedDict(dic)

In [11]: list(odic.keys())[2:]
Out[11]: ['F', 'Gs']
```

Answer (score 1):

Словари в Python являются неупорядоченными структурами данных. Обращение по ключу происходит за счет хэширования. Именно поэтому ваш вопрос не имеет под собой основания. 
Чтобы реализовать нечто похожее используйте структуру данных OrderedDict.

Comment: С помощью `OrderedDict` это тоже нельзя реализовать. Это подкласс `dict`. Он запоминает изначальный порядок, но не связывает ключи с индексами.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже было сказано, ключи в словаре не имеют определенного порядка. Если нужно пройтись по ключам в лексикографическом порядке, то такое решение:

Сортируем ключи, потом проходимся по ним. Пока не встретили ключ F - ничего не печатаем.

```
dic = {'A': 213, 'B': 1424, 'F': 412, 'Gs': 'asf'}

print_key = False

for key in sorted(dic): 
    if key == 'F': 
        print_key = True

    if print_key: 
        print(key)
```

Вывод:

```
F
Gs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num_of_row = 2    
for i, x in enumerate(dic):
    if i>=num_of_row:
        print(i,x)
```